# Android ListView update after asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a problem with my adapter for my listview, i don't know where i have to add notifyDataSetChanged() in my code always if i run this code in logcat is coming a error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131165276, class android.widget.ListView)]
```

my asynctask:

```
    class UpdateData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {
    String result = "";
    JSONArray jArray = null;


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter.addAll(deptList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ....

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
                EventCalendarStrings d = new EventCalendarStrings();
                d.name = j.optString("name", "");
                d.kategorie = j.optString("Art", "");
                deptList.add(d);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "No connection " + e.toString());
        }
        }
        return jArray;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that deptList (better use local UpdateData class storage) is only used in one thread. Because it is outer variable I suspect it is used in the adapter as it's data and... Maybe I am wrong but I don't see the code.

Comment: Is `deptList` the data source for your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

It goes in `onPostExecute()` because it is executed on the UI thread. Calling it in `doInBackground()` will result in that exception.

Comment: i tried it in onPostExecute() but wasn't successful

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                adapter.addAll(deptList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
    }
```

or

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                adapter.addAll(deptList);
                listview.setAdapater(adapter);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: ur asynctask code is in activity only right? If not then activity.runOnUiThread

Comment: now he accepted the code with runOnUiThread but there is still the error

Comment: I have modified the answer, u can try the other option

Comment: Which version of android ur testing? If possible u can test in another android version...

Comment: Have u checked in any other version of android?